# consuming from context provider returns element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that queries a collection based on a user input collected from an input field. When the user inputs his value the app redirects to another page where I want to display my `searchResults`. I am trying to achieve this using Context. I have created my Context in the first component, but when I use the input field to type something and send it I get this error:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `SearchResultsPage`.
```

What am I missing here and how can I show `searchResults` in my `SearchResults` component?

here is my first component with the input field:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
export const SearchContext = React.createContext();

class Search extends Component {
    state = {
        searchResults: [],
        isSearched: false
    }

    data = { searchResults: this.state.searchResults }

    getSearchQuery = (event) => {
        const queryString = document.querySelector(
            ".search-input"
        ).value;

        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            axios.post("http://localhost:3001/search", {
                queryString: queryString,


            }).then(response => {

                this.setState({ ...this.state, searchResults: response.data });

            });
            this.setState({ ...this.state, isSearched: true });
            window.location.href = '/blog/searchResults'
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <SearchContext.Provider value={this.state.searchResults}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="search-input"
                    onKeyDown={(e) => this.getSearchQuery(e)}
                />
            </SearchContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default Search;
```

and here is my searchResults component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Footer from '../Footer/Footer.jsx';
import CustomHeader from '../CustomHeader/CustomHeader.jsx';
import Search from '../Search/Search.jsx';
import SearchContext from '../../components/Search/Search.jsx';
let title = 'Search Results'

class SearchResultsPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <CustomHeader
                    title={title}
                />

                <Search />
                <SearchContext.Consumer>
                    {value => value.postContent}
                </SearchContext.Consumer>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        )
    }
};



export default SearchResultsPage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SearchContext` is exported as a [named export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export), so you need to import it accordingly:

```
import { SearchContext } from '../../components/Search/Search.jsx';
```

Also, since `Search` and `SearchContext` are in the same file, you can combine their imports (assuming `../../components/Search` and `../Search/` are the same):

```
import Search, { SearchContext } from '../Search/Search.jsx';
```